# efax-gtk bionic

Tags: fax

```
efax-0.9a: 17:04:39 Error: tcgetattr on fd=7 failed: Input/output error
modem setting ttyS0

efax-0.9a: 17:42:22 Error: can't open serial port /dev/ttyACM0: No such file or directory
setting ttyACM0
```

just want to send efax. I would appreciate any help you can give. I am new to this type of OS. TY

Answer (score 0):

Did you run Efax-gtk like this?

/usr/bin/efax-gtk

[image]

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer… Also please crop your screenshots.

Comment: I don't see how much more I can crop. I am attempting to help as there are different ways of running Efax.

Comment: @Melebius I cropped the screenshot. It's not necessarily "more like a comment than an answer" because of the part of the screenshot that says `Socket running on port 9900` and also the Fax entry method.

Comment: @karel Thank you for processing the image. However, I cannot understand why the mentioned message should make it a valid answer. Probably the answerer should explain it better.

Comment: i ran that command via terminal and no " (as superuser)" was added to the gui. I got the exact same results.  Is there another way for me to run as super user?

Comment: I would recommend uninstalling it and reinstalling BOTH efax and efax-gtk. Also which Ubuntu and version number. @Hon Estman

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
i used synaptic to dl and install b.t.w. Shouldn't i be running pretty much everything as a superuser anyway? I am new and use gui which seems to me to also protect against me jacking up my distro, so being a SU in gui should be pretty safe, right? For all i know, my personal computer could be wide open to the world right now because I have taken the easy route with gui but I wanted to get stuff done and the tutorials I watched didn't seem so cut and dry.

Comment: I plan on reinstall this evening after work. Should i purge via terminal or is the gui method sufficient?

Comment: also i clicked on your bio to pm a ty but didn't find a way to do that so i put it here. i appreciate your help. and i noticed that we have much in common.

Comment: You can purge either way. I have the same distro. I'm at https://www.unix.com/. as drew77